# How do you get the next key in an associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

There are a lot of questions about this and they all use `next($array)` and then `key($array)` which is fine, accept when you have an array with potential null values, such as iterating over an excel row. Allow me to demonstrate.

Consider the following array:

```
$headings = [ 'A' => NULL, 'B' => 'Hello', 'C' => NULL, 'D' => 'World', 'E' => NULL]
```

I created a for each loop as such:

```
foreach ($headings as $key => $value) {
    if ($value !== null) {
        var_dump('Current Key: ' . $key);
        var_dump($value);
        next($headings);
        var_dump('Next Key: ' . key($headings));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string(14) "Current Key: B"
string(5) "Hello"
string(11) "Next Key: B"
string(14) "Current Key: D"
string(5) "World"
string(11) "Next Key: C"
```

Current key as expected is correct, the next key is wrong. Is there a trick I am missing when inside an if statement? it should be:

```
string(14) "Current Key: B"
string(5) "Hello"
string(11) "Next Key: C"
string(14) "Current Key: D"
string(5) "World"
string(11) "Next Key: E"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with null values. When you call `next()`, it causes the iteration through the loop to go to the next element. That causes `foreach` to skip that element.

Comment: @Barmar So whats the correct way to get the next key in this case?